# Why lambda function doesn't work with std::min_element?

Tags: c++, lambda

I wrote a program to find the lexicographically minimum string in a vector of strings using `std::min_element`, but I want to get the minimum string that its length is greater than 1. I tried to do `std::min_element` with lambda expressions, but I got a compilation error.

I've tried to search for that, but couldn't get anything that solves the problem.

```
vector<string> names{"Jason", "Peter", "A", "Ac", "O"};
cout << *min_element(names.begin(), names.end(), [](string s) {return s.length() > 1;}) << '\n';
```

PS: I'm expecting this to print "Ac".

Comment: Post a [mcve] reproducing your problem an the exact verbatim error message as required here please.

Comment: The third argument is supposed to be a comparison function that defines what "minimum" means. You can't just give it some function and expect it to know that you want the lexicographically minimum element for which that function evaluates to true.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have a single function that separates the strings longer than `1` and also finds the minimum among them. I suspect you may need to copy out the relevant strings or else remove them to the back of the vector with `std::remove_if` before finding the minimum. Which approach would depend on whether or not you can modify the vector.

Answer (score 2):

The signature of the comparison function of [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) should be equivalent to the following one.
This is the reason why you are getting the compilation error:

```
bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

Since [`operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) is overloaded for `std::string` to compare lexicographically, you can get the desired result by sorting `names` with the default comparator and then finding the first element with the length grater than 1 as follows:

[**Live DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iIDRBaJRItQ83gEQ)

```
std::vector<std::string> names{"Jason", "Peter", "A", "Ac", "O"};

std::sort(names.begin(), names.end());

const auto it = std::find_if(
                    names.cbegin(), names.cend(),
                    [](const std::string& str){return str.size() > 1;});

if(it != names.cend()){
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to keep the original vector `names`, you should copy it before sorting, or use `std::set` as follows:

[**Live DEMO (std::set)**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oFTsLElIOIQQXDFw)

```
std::vector<std::string> names{"Jason", "Peter", "A", "Ac", "O"};

std::set<std::string> s(names.cbegin(), names.cend());

const auto it = std::find_if(
                    s.cbegin(), s.cend(),
                    [](const std::string& str){return str.size() > 1;});

if(it != s.cend()){
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the last parameter. It's expecting a `Compare` and, being simple, a `Compare` takes two parameters and returns true or false. See the template definition of min_element taken from [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/):

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class Compare>
ForwardIterator min_element (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Compare comp);
```

You can fix it easily adding another parameter and ignoring it.

```
vector<string> names{"Jason", "Peter", "A", "Ac", "O"};
cout << *min_element(names.begin(), names.end(), [](string s, string y) {return s.length() > 1;}) << '\n';
```

You can also search more about `Compare` as you'll end up using it pretty often.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although not answering the question, a solution is to first sort the vector by string length, then using the lambda function in `std::find_if`

Answer (score 0):

You can define the compare function so that an element of length smaller or equal to 1 is greater than a longer element.

```
bool special_comparison(const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2)
{
    // Make a short string appears greater than a longer one.
    bool shortString1 = s1.size() <= 1;
    bool shortString2 = s2.size() <= 1;
    if (shortString1 != shortString2)
        return shortString2;

    // Regular comparison if both strings are short or both are long.
    return s1 < s2;
}
```

If the minimum element has a length of 1 (or 0), then it means that all elements are short.

If data is unsorted and you only need to find minimum a single time, that would probably be the fastest approach. Otherwise (if you need to process items in order), it might be better to first sort the data as suggested in other solution.